# Routing & Linking Models

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I have a these two models: `rooms` and `scores` in a CakePHP setup.

`rooms` hasMany `scores`, and `scores` belongsTo `rooms`.

The current default routing is as follows:

- /rooms/
- /rooms/add
- /rooms/view/*
- /rooms/edit/*
- /scores
- /scores/add
- /scores/edit/*

I would like to route it like this:

- /session *(controller: rooms / action: index)*
- /session/add *(controller: rooms / action: add)*
- /session/* *(controller: rooms / action: view)*
- /session/*/edit *(controller: rooms / action: edit)*
- /session/*/scores/* *(controller: scores / action: view)*
- /session/*/scores/add *(controller: scores / action: add)*
- /session/*/scores/*/edit *(controller: scores / action: edit)*

(I had to use `Rooms` instead of `Sessions` as `Sessions` seems to be internally reserved within CakePHP.)

EDIT: Sorry, the question was...

How do I route this:
`/session/*/scores/*/edit` (controller: scores / action: edit) such that the first * will correspond to the room id and the second * corresponds to the score id that belongs to that particular room.

Comment: Please clarify - what is the actual question?  Are you looking for someone to write your routes for you?

Comment: I haven't checked this, but I suspect only 'Session' as name for a model may conflict with the SessionComponent. Controller should probably be fine. Rewarding the routing. What have you tried? Please edit your question and add the code of your custom routes and explain what errors or problems you're having

Comment: @thaJeztah in the Controller page, wouldn't `$this->Room->...` conflict with `$this->Session->...`? For instance, `$this->Session->setFlash()`

Comment: @jon If the Controller is called `SessionsController` (plural), that should not be a problem. However, the *model* cannot be named 'Session'. So if you name your model `Room`, but the *controller* `SessionsController` it should work. You can load the Room-model in your SessionsController via the `$uses` property, that way CakePHP will not start looking for a 'Session' model